# How to batch rename a fasta file from the full Genbank details to just organism name?

Tags: bioinformatics, fasta

I got this data from batch entrez, and the format is:

```
>OM719994.1 Isoetes dixitii isolate EL136 internal transcribed spacer 1, partial sequence; 5.8S ribosomal RNA gene, complete sequence; and internal transcribed spacer 2, partial sequence
ACACACGTCCCTGCAAACTG...
```

But I want it to be:

```
>Isoetes dixitii
ACACACGTCCCTGCAAACTG...
```

There are 1,500 sequences in each of 10 files and I cannot do this manually but can't work out how to do it with find/replace in Notepad or Notepad++, or CMD.

Comment: Please edit the question to show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic]. Also, do you always want to keep just the 2nd and 3rd words in every fasta description?

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -lane 'if ( m{^>} ) { print ">$F[1] $F[2]"; } else { print; }' file1.fasta file2.fasta ...
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.
`-a` : Split `$_` into array `@F` on whitespace or on the regex specified in `-F` option.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

`m{^>}` : match the fasta headers, that is, lines starting with `>`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: Thanks Timur Shtatland, works like a charm.